# Product link redirects to home page

Tags: product

When I copy and paste a link to a product into the address bar and press ENTER, the page is redirected to the homepage.  If I email myself the product using Magento's share feature, when I receive the email and click it, I am not redirected to the homepage.

I need to be able to offer links to certain products, is there a setting for this?

The link sent in the email is no different than what I would get when copying the link in the address bar.  It doesn't make sense; it's as if Magento knows the referrer is not from the current page... or from one of those email shares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a vhost and it seems to be the default one also.

If you don't use the www before the url the server redirects you to the default vhosts which has the www in front of it.

That is why you were being redirected to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was that I did not include the `www` in the URL.  I don't understand why it would do this, but oh well, its works.